# Display one DIV directly below dynamically changing DIV

Tags: css, html

I have one DIV, which changes height depending on data which a user enters into it. Once they are finished, they click a button and a second DIV appears below it with all the data displayed in a table.
The second DIV is always on the page, but it's opacity is set to 0.

As the first DIV can be anywhere from 100px to 1000px in height, how can I get the second DIV to always display directly below it? Ive been playing around with margins and paddings but I just can't get the second DIV to appear dynamically in the right spot.

Preferably using CSS if thats an option.

Thanks.

Comment: post what you have tried...?

Comment: a div is a block level element, so it will automatic? I dont understand you question

Comment: Put them in a container with height auto and width = to first div, after that simply float them left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the CSS *position* property is set to *relative* in your divs. Something like:

HTML:

```
<div class="user_input_data"></div>
<div class="results hidden"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.user_input_data
{
    position: relative;
}
div.results
{
    position: relative;
}
div.hidden
{
    display: none;
}
div.block
{
    display: block;
}
```

Then you'd have to remove *hidden* class and add *block* class to show your results.

Answer (score 1):

if div is a **block** (is default) it will show in bottom of first div

```
<div class="firstDiv"></div>
<div class="secondDiv"></div>
```

if you want second div overlap first div and move by scrolling you should use CSS position property

```
.secondDiv{
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: If it a block, *without* floating properties and position. Of course.